# How to remove NA values in a specific column of a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have a data frame with a large number of observations and I want to remove NA values in 1 specific column while keeping the rest of the data frame the same. I want to do this without using na.omit(). How do I do this?

Comment: You cannot remove NA values without removing either the entire row or the entire column, or replacing the NA values with a value.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `is.na` or `complete.cases` to return a logical vector for `subset`ting

```
subset(df1, complete.cases(colnm))
```

where `colnm` is the actual column name

Comment: I see, thank you. How would we use is.na?

Comment: @AnastasiaSo `is.na` returns TRUE where there are NA elements, negate (`!`) and it changes the TRUE to non-NA, i.e. `subset(df1, !is.na(colnm))`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr) 

df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,NA), 
                 b = c(5,NA,8))
filter(df, !is.na(a))

# output 
a  b
1 1  5
2 2 NA
```